# Modal hide trobleshooting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a module where a dropdown modal has to appear after a duration of 3 mins on the page. It has an input field where digits has to be entered by the user and when he clicks on 'save', the modal should hide.  Although I am getting the modal at correct time and when the digits are entered the values are being saved too but only the modal does not hides. I am just unable to figure out the reason behind it as the modal implementation is correct up to my knowledge. I am new to jquery and javascript so need suggestions and expertise of community. I am putting my code here, please have a look and any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal"  role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->

    <form name="frmActive" id="frmActive" action="" method="post">      
          <div class="modal-content" style="height:250px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Ideal Time activation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Please enter activation PIN:</p>
              <p id="msg" style="color:#F00;"></p>
              <input type="password" name="pin" id="pin" value="" maxlength="4"  onKeyUp="checkNumber(this)"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pin">
              <input type="hidden" id="inactiveTime">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save</button>

           <input type="hidden" id="module_id" value="<?php echo $moduleId ; ?>">
           <input type="hidden" id="chapter_id" value="<?php echo $chapterId ; ?>">

            </div>
          </div>
    </form>      


        </div>
      </div>
jQuery("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){

    var pin             =   jQuery("#pin").val();
    var chapter_id      =   jQuery("#chapter_id").val();
    var module_id       =   jQuery("#module_id").val();
    var nowDate         =   jQuery.now();
    var inactiveTime    =   jQuery("#inactiveTime").val();
    var seconds         =   (nowDate - inactiveTime) / 1000;

    var formData    =   new FormData();
      formData.append("pin", pin);
      formData.append("seconds", seconds);
      formData.append("module_id", module_id);
      formData.append("chapter_id", chapter_id);
 // $("#spinner").show(); 
      $.ajax({
        url: "processActivation.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        //dataType:'json',
        success: function(result){          

        if(result == 'active')
            {
        $("#bt").html(result) ;
                jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }


    else    if(result == 'active')
            {

                jQuery('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
            else
            {
                $("#msg").html(result) ;

            }

        }
      });
});
```

And the ajax request being made for success,

```
$dataactivation =   array("user_id"=>$uid, "module_id"=>$moduleId, "chapter_id"=>$chapterId,"time_taken"=>$time_taken, "created"=>$created);
    $db->query_insert("tbl_activation", $dataactivation);   
  echo trim('active');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove echo trim('active');

change to : header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);

echo json_encode('active')); exit();

i hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. That's the exact solution. :) Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try console.log your result, you need to know the respond.

console.log(result);

here is the problem: if(result == 'active')

Comment: I tried as per suggestion. It gives `ReferenceError: trim is not defined`

Comment: it's an Ajax, you need JSON to respond, from where trim('active') is ?
change your echo trim and try this
`code`
    header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success','data' => 'active'));
    exit();

Comment: May I know where to place this code you just sent. Bit confused

Comment: it's an Ajax, you need JSON to respond, from where trim('active') is ?
change your echo trim and try this
inline `code
    header('Content-Type: application/json', true, 200);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'active'));
    exit();
`

and change this: if(result == 'active')
into this: if(result['status'] == 'active')

Comment: can you please tell me where an d how to place the code you sent. May be I am making mistake from my side.